# Axios get : response with 403 error forbidden

Tags: vue.js, axios, get

I'm trying to use Open API in Vue.js.

When the webpage was created, i just wanna check the fetched data on console log.

This is the error image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/299g4.png)

And this is Network tab. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoNtd.png)

**code**

```js
    created() {
        const request = require("request");
        const SERVIECE_KEY ="   blah blah"; // secret
        let url =
          "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://openapi.molit.go.kr:8081/OpenAPI_ToolInstallPackage/service/rest/RTMSOBJSvc/getRTMSDataSvcAptTrade";

                 // use 'herokuapp' as a proxy server 

        let queryParams =
          "?" +
          encodeURIComponent("serviceKey") +
          `=${SERVIECE_KEY}`;
        queryParams +=
          "&" +
          encodeURIComponent("LAWD_CD") +
          "=" +
          encodeURIComponent("11110"); 
        queryParams +=
          "&" +
          encodeURIComponent("DEAL_YMD") +
          "=" +
          encodeURIComponent("201512");

        request(
          {
            url: url + queryParams,
            method: "GET",
          },
          function (error, response, body) {
            console.log("Status", response.statusCode);
            console.log("Headers", JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log("Reponse received", body);
          }
        );
      },
```

**Try**

- The same request works on Postman with encoded service key (no proxy server URL).
- it works on a browser as well.
- Use decoded and encoded service key both above the code to check if the URL i entered is wrong

I know 403 error(forbidden) is due to the permission to access.

But i really don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: I think you need to configure CORS in your site

Comment: Oops! i didn't see this, "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://openapi.molit.go.kr:8081/OpenAPI_ToolInstallPackage/service/rest/RTMSOBJSvc/getRTMSDataSvcAptTrade" please check this URL, it is wrong, you cannot have two http in one address.

Comment: Hi Emeka, 
According to your advice, i searched some docs about how to use this kind of proxy URL.
And i found the usage like me.
https://github.com/Isoaxe/ravenous/blob/master/src/util/searchYelp.js
plz check 5 line.

Comment: Hi, did it work for you or are you having any more bugs?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives me 403 error